# Python a function that counts lines and characters in a file

Tags: python, function, count

Could anyone please take a look at what I've made so far? I haven't succeeded in locating the problem myself yet.

```
def txt_file(file1):
    file1 = open('text.txt', 'r')
    linecount = 0
    charcount = 0
    for line in file1:
        linecount +=1
        for char in line:
            charcount += 1
    print "file1 contains", linecount, "lines and", charcount, "characters."
    file1.close()
```

Comment: The argument you pass in is useless because you immediately overwrite the value on the first line of your function. You can remove that from the parameter list. Also `for char in line: charcount+=1` can be shortened to `charcount += len(line)`. You probably want to print outside of the for loop as well so I'd recommend unindenting the print statement by one level.

Comment: So whats your problem????

Comment: What is the problem? Are you simply getting a printed line of updated results for each line in the file? If that's the issue, move the `print` statement out of the `for` loop.

Comment: Don't indent the `print` statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is much easier this way:

```
with open('text.txt') as the_file:
     data = [len(i) for i in the_file]
     line, char = len(data), sum(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your code:

- indentation
- print must be outside the line loop
- you declare a function argument that you actually don't use

try this code:

```
file1 = open('textfile.txt', 'r')
linecount = 0
charcount = 0
for line in file1:
    linecount +=1
    for char in line:
        charcount += 1
print ("file1 contains", linecount, "lines and", charcount, "characters.")
file1.close()
```

If you need a function define and call it in this way:

```
def txt_file():
    file1 = open('textfile.txt', 'r')
    linecount = 0
    charcount = 0
    for line in file1:
        linecount +=1
        for char in line:
            charcount += 1
    print ("file1 contains", linecount, "lines and", charcount, "characters.")
    file1.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    txt_file()
```

On a sample file containing the following three lines:

```
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
```

it produces the following output:

```
file1 contains 3 lines and 33 characters.
```

(it counts also space and newline)

Comment: The question is likely in Python 2, in which `print` is a statement rather than a function and therefore does not need parentheses.

Comment: That's right. I edited the answer removing the point about print syntax.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the for loop:

```
for line in file1:
    line += 1
```

The variable `line` in the for loop is just what the variable that iterates over is called, and has nothing to do with what you're looking for. Instead, after doing some research, try this for lines:

```
linecount = open(file1).read().count('\n')
```

And for characters, use the for loop to exclude spaces:

```
for i in file1:
    if i != " ":
        charcount += 1
```

Comment: That will fail with a traceback when the interpreter tries to add a `str` to an `int`. Cast each `int` to a `str`, or leave it as it was (which was perfectly fine).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the print statement is indented once too much. It is executed every for loop and needs to be moved out to the end.

The better way to do this would be to use `len`:

```
file1=open("foo.txt", "r").readlines()

linecount=len(x)
charcount=sum(map(len, x))

print "file1 contains {0} lines and {1} characters".format(linecount, charcount)
```

The charcount works because it takes the len of every line and then sums them.